# Keep textarea open despite 140 limit when clicking a specific div below it jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Earlier today, I posted a post regarding 140 char limit, that part is now solved. 
Now, I am out for another tricky thing, and that is to keep the 140 char limit control, and still maintain another check, that is to check whether a specific part of a div is clicked or NOT, if DIV is clicked the textarea should remain open i.e. 80px high, does not matter if the char limiter reports 140 or 139 and so one. But if clicking outside this DIV the textarea should go back to its initial height that is 19px, if the limiter reports 140, else it will remain open;

Here's my jQuery:

```
$(".comment-box").focus(function(){
        var parent = $(this).parent();
        $('#' + this.id).css({ 'height' : '80px' });
        $(parent).find('.comment-toolbar').css({ 'display' : 'block' });    
    }),
    $('.comment-toolbar').click(function(e){
        if(e.target == "in_or_out"){
            console.log("inside"); 
            $(".comment-box").css({ 'height' : '80px' }); 
        }
        else{ console.log("outside");  }
    }),
    $('.comment-box').focusout(function(){
        var parent = $(this).parent();
        if($(this).val().length > 0){

        }
        else{
            $('#' + this.id).css({ 'height' : '19px' });
            $(parent).find('.comment-toolbar').css({ 'display' : 'none' }); 
        }
    });
```

and here's a jsfiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/3sCfG/56/

Comment: Are you just trying to get the comment box to close on focusout no matter if there is text in it or not?

Comment: $('#' + this.id) - you could just use $(this)

Comment: @ExceptionLimeCat  If there is text, it should remain open e.g. if the char limit says 139, this is measured by the length property, I want the textarea to remain expanded. If however, I click a specific DIV right below it, BTW, the class for this DIV is .comment-toolbar, I want the textarea to remain expanded even if the char limit reports 140 or below 140 e.g. 139, 138 and so one. But if the user click anywhere else on the DOM it should go back to normal if the limiter reports 140, else remain expanded. A bit complex.

Comment: @Pete          AFAIK, I need to use the ID not the this which is the Object itself. Not sure exactly, but will keep it this way for now, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: You really _should_ be using `$(this)` - Pete is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may have found a solution to your problem. It's not the cleanest solution but it works. I had to use mouse position to track where the click came from bc the `focusout` event fires before the click and there was no way to tell where the click came from other than mouse location.

The part that isn't so 'clean' is the if statement i had to use to check if the click was within the confines of the toolbar. Maybe you can figure out a better way of checking that.

JS:

```
var mousePos;
var hasFocus = false;//This is used to prevent the window.click from firing after a focus event

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
  mousePos = e;
 }); 
});

$(".comment-box").keydown(function () {
  var parent = $(this).parent();
  var text_max = 140;
  var length_reached = $(this).val().length;
  var remaining = text_max - length_reached;

  $(parent).find('.counter').html(remaining);

  if (remaining < 5 || remaining >= text_max) $(parent).find(".btn").prop("disabled", true);
  else $(parent).find(".btn").prop("disabled", false);
});

$(".comment-box").focus(function(e){
        var parent = $(this).parent();
        $('#' + this.id).css({ 'height' : '80px' });
        $(parent).find('.comment-toolbar').css({ 'visibility' : 'visible'});
        hasFocus = true;            
    });


 $('.comment-box').focusout(function(e){
var parent = $(this).parent();

var toolbox = $(parent).find('.comment-toolbar');
var offset = $(toolbox).offset();

    //Check if click occured within toolbar
if(mousePos.pageX >= offset.left && mousePos.pageY >= offset.top && mousePos.pageX <= (offset.left + $(toolbox).width()) && mousePos.pageY <= (offset.top + $(toolbox).height()))
{

}   
else if($(this).val().length > 0){

}
else{
    $('#' + this.id).css({ 'height' : '19px' });
    $(parent).find('.comment-toolbar').css({ 'visibility' : 'hidden' });    
}

hasFocus = false;
});

$(window).click(function(){
console.log('window click');
if(!hasFocus)
{
    for(var i=0;$('.comment-box').length;i++)
    {
        var commentbox = $('.comment-box')[i];
        var toolbox = $('.comment-toolbar')[i];
        var offset = $(toolbox).offset();

        if(mousePos.pageX >= offset.left && mousePos.pageY >= offset.top && mousePos.pageX <= (offset.left + $(toolbox).width()) && mousePos.pageY <= (offset.top + $(toolbox).height()))
        {
            return false;
        }   
        else if($(commentbox).val().length > 0){

        }
        else{
            $(commentbox).css({ 'height' : '19px' });
            $(toolbox).css({ 'visibility' : 'hidden' });    
        }
    }
}
});
```

I had to make a minor CSS change bc the toolbar was getting a weird positioning after the first focusout.

CSS:

```
.comment-toolbar{
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid red; 
  width: 420px; 
  height: 45px;
  float: right; 
  visibility: hidden;/* Use visibility instead of display to show/hide toolbar */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExceptionLimeCat/Gx3tV/

Hopefully that helps.